# SSL Key Exchange

Tags: tls, key-exchange

I read briefly over the TSL/SSL key exchange protocol. I have to wonder about the whole pre-master-key procedure. Wouldn't it be sufficient if the client or server encrypted a generated session key with the other sides public key? Why the extra work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nonces prevent replay attacks. If the server didn't include a value into the handshake that's different for each connection, an attacker can record a connection and replay it. Mixing a server determined nonce into the key is an easy way to prevent such attacks.

Comment: Okay, good point. So when the client generates the session key, one could easily repeat the exact same conversation later. One doesn't know what effects that will have, but they're potentially not desired. But when the server generates the session key - shouldn't that be fine? Is there some technical reason why the server doesn't just generate the full session key and sends it to the client?

Comment: How would that work? You can't encrypt the session key with the client's public key, because it usually doesn't have one. There are different ways to avoid replay problems, using a nonce on both sides that's mixed into the session key is just one easy solution.

Comment: The client usually doesn't have a public key? Why not? Is it that hard to generate one?

Comment: Generating one is easy in principle, but apart from client authentication(rarely used) and ephemeral key-change(for forward privacy) it's not that useful. IMO one should always use ECDHE where neither side creates the session key, and instead it's the result of a key-exchange operation.

Comment: So the method would be secure (assuming no one can manipulate the connection), but you would prefer a key agreement instead of a key transport protocol. May I ask why? It just seems like more work to me. Which properties does key agreement have that make it preferable?

Comment: I can't say if a method is secure unless I get a clear description of it. The purpose of ephermeral key-exchange is to provide forward secrecy. So when you lose your long term private key, an attacker can't decrypt recorded connections.

Comment: Clear description: Client sends public key to server. Server generates random symmetric key (+IV), encrypts it with the clients public key and sends it to the client. The following communication is encrypted with the symmetric key. (Assuming the messages can be read by a third party, but not manipulated.) -- The forward secrecy argument convinced me. Didn't think of that, thanks. :)

Comment: "Assuming the messages can be read by a third party, but not manipulated." We generally avoid that assumption, since usually being in a position to read messages allows you to manipulate them as well.

Comment: Well but key agreement isn't secure without additional measurements as well if the data can be manipulated? At least that's how I understand it. I also don't know of any method that can provide authenticity without a write-secure-channel existing at some point before the key agreement. That's why I excluded that possibility. Is there such a method? I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: The standard technique is trusting the installed software(in particular the installed root certificates) and CAs which sign a certificate only for the legitimate owner of a domain.